# Weka clustering using word frequency csv file

Tags: java, data-mining, weka

I have a csv file in this format:

`<userName>, word1=<word1Frequency>, word2=<word2Frequency>, ...`

The first problem is, this csv file does not have a header, which is required by WEKA. What should the header be like? Should it just be 
`username, word1, word2, ...`

Also, to import for clustering, is it OK if it put 1 file per user under a common directory? I am very new to this. I have used mallet before so feel free to use reference of mallet.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert it to ARFF format, you will need to assign each unique word a column ID.
Then convert the vectors to ARFF sparse vectors, which look like this:

```
{<colnr> <value>, <colnr> <value>, ...}
```

Where colnr is the *integer* attribute number (the unique column ID you assigned to the word). They must be ordered ascendingly, I believe.

Alternatively, you could give [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) a try. It seems to have *much* more clustering than Weka. It has a parser API for a couple of formats, maybe one of these formats suits your needs, or can more easily adopted to your needs.

[TermFrequencyParser](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/datasource/parser/TermFrequencyParser.java) seems to be almost what you need:

> A parser to load term frequency data, which essentially are sparse vectors
>   with text keys.
>
> Parse a file containing term frequencies. The expected format is 'label term1  term2  ...'. Terms must not contain the separator character!

You can probably just set the separator pattern to `[, =]+` and it will read your file right away.

Comment: Awesome! just what I was looking for. I was thinking the wrong way. I have to put individual words in '@Attribute' not in '@Data'. Thanks a lot for the response. In the meantime, I will definitely take a look at ELKI. It does seem to have what I am looking for. But I don't understand why would anyone give me a downvote for asking this question :S

Comment: I assume you got the downvote for not having researched enough. There are plenty of Weka ARFF file examples. Plus, the Weka mailing list is very helpful, and a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

convert your file/s to ARFF format, with a header as described here:

http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29

about reading files from multiple directories, I believe this example could help:

http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+files+from+Text+Collections

HTH

Comment: @ihadanny thank you for your response. I've gone through all the tutorials from the official site, but I still cannot get a hang of it. I manually converted my csv file to ARFF format from my program using this syntax `@RELATION wordfrequency

@ATTRIBUTE word string
@ATTRIBUTE frequency numeric

@DATA
{2 francear,2 rt,1 obama,1 profilechairman,1 profilevice,1 profiledarwish,1 profileholding}` But I still cannot get the usernames included in my data. That is, I have a collection of 100,000 data in this format. How to include all of them? Or am I thinking the wrong way?